# Test containers: manipulate existing docker compose services

Tags: testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

I'm using Maven pre-integration-tests and post-integration tests to setup and tear down a test environment with three services (say A, B and C)

Is it possible using Test containers to restart one of those services before a test? If not, can I do that using other docker library for Java?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your test is something similar to this.

```java
@Container
public GenericContainer container = new GenericContainer(...);
```

You can use junit5 `BeforeEach` and `AfterEach` annotations to restart your containers before/after running your tests cases.

```java
@BeforeEach
public void beforeEach() {
  container.start();
}

@AfterEach
public void afterEach() {
  container.stop();
}
```

If you need to restart the container only before specific test, you can try reorganizing your test methods using @Nested [annotation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-nested)

Comment: Is there any way to attach test containers to an existing docker container and then start/stop it?